# How to better structure the code

Tags: java, android

I was wondering on how to go about creating a quiz environment inside of android.  What I do not want is to open up a new activity every time someone gets the answer correct because there is over 100 questions.

I am using g a radio group for thr answers a textview for the questions and a button to get to the next question,

So for now my code looks something like this

```
   String questions[] = {"question1" , "question2".....};

  If (textview.gettext= "question1" && radioA.is selected= true) {
             RadioA.setText ("newAnswerHere");
              RadioB.setText("......)
    }
```

Now I know I can use a switch statement  but there has to be an easier way to do this? Is there not?

Comment: Any link or something would help so I don't have to make a million activities or lines of code.

Comment: Use `==` for comparing :)

Comment: try to use abstraction. You just need to create 1 activity and reuse it, sending the necessary data to show

Comment: @gian1200 abstraction do you have a link or something? I'm googling it now

Comment: well, abstraction may not be the right word to google. what I meant was to use "Factorization" in your code. Imagine yourself writing 100 activities, then start thinking what do they have in common and extract it. What do you have? That is what you have "to code". Later you will be able to reuse it with the appropriate data (let the computer do the work for you and not otherwise

Comment: So kinda like rogue said create an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always recommend the simplest pattern: [extract method](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html)

### First step

```
String questions[] = {"question1", "question2".....};

if (isQuestion1Selected()) {
  setNewAnswersHere()
}

private boolean isQuestionSelected() {    
    return textview.gettext().equals("question1") && radioA.isSelected == true;
}

private void setNewAnswersHere(){
    RadioA.setText("newAnswerHere");
    RadioB.setText("......);
}
```

But this is just first step :)

---

### Second step

```
String questions[] = {"question1", "question2".....};

if (isQuestionSelected(1)) {
  setNewAnswersHere()
}

private boolean isQuestionSelected(int number) {    
    return textview.gettext().equals("question" +  number) && radioA.isSelected == true;
}

private void setNewAnswersHere(){
    RadioA.setText("newAnswerHere");
    RadioB.setText("......);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't String objects always be compared with .equals instead of ==?

Comment: to avoid weird bugs -> yes!

Comment: Then I would have to do it for every question?

Comment: @RichTalcik This depends, I added second refactoring step.

Comment: OK so doing it this way would make it cleaner by far

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a "Question" object?:

```
public class Question {

    String question;
    String[] answers;
    String correct;

    //methods

}
```

Using that, you could store them in a data object and then use those instead of fixed arrays

Comment: No I have not would this be the best way to go? And if I do how would I check the answers?

Comment: Make accessor methods, `getAnswer()`, use a [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) for setting up a question. Would be a lot cleaner imo :)

Comment: Yes cleaner for sure still a lot coding that will be needed for 200 questions lmao!

Comment: Try using a file for storing data. It's much easier to iterate over something like a text file than manually inserting the data.